# block cipher and AES encryption mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, aes

I am using AES and Crypto to implement the following two classes. This is the AESCipher class which takes a message, and returns an encryption of it using Crypto the python library.

```
BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]

class AESCipher: 
    def __init__(self,sec_param):
        self.sec_param = sec_param
        self.key = os.urandom(sec_param)
    #msg is string only 
    def encrypt( self, msg):
        msg = pad(msg)
        tweak = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CFB, tweak )
        return base64.b64encode(tweak + cipher.encrypt( msg ) ) 
    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        tweak = enc[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CFB, tweak)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc[16:] ))
```

and the class BC, which stands for block cipher.

```
class BC(object):
def __init__(self, sec_param):
    self.sec_param = sec_param
def encrypt(self, message):
    return AESCipher(sec_param).encrypt(message) 
def decrypt(self, encryption):
    return AESCipher(self.sec_param).decrypt(encryption)
```

My problem however is that, though this seems like it should work, it does not. I'm calling AESCipher to encrypt and decrypt much like in the AESCipher class, but the results are different, and the decryption does not return the original message in this case. I dont know why that happens given that it is the same methods/classes that are being called.

Example:

```
msg = '100011010111110'
sec_param = 16
bc = BC(sec_param)
encr = bc.encrypt(msg)
decr = bc.decrypt(encr)

new_cipher = AESCipher(sec_param)
C = new_cipher.encrypt(msg)
D= new_cipher.decrypt(C)
```

I would expect encr to be equal to C, and decr to be equal to D. I also expect decr to actually return the msg. But none of these happen. What is the reason?

edit1: the AESCipher class on its own works. It encrypts and decrypts correctly.

Comment: `AESCipher(sec_param).encrypt(message)` should be `AESCipher(self.sec_param).encrypt(message)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're generating a fresh key during the instantiation of `AESCipher`. If you use the same instance for encryption and decryption, you will also use the same key and everything will be OK. If you use different `AESCipher` instances, then you will have different keys and a wrong decrypted text.

Keys are usually passed into the function from outside and not generated by the cipher object itself.

Answer (score 1):

`encr` is not equal to `C` because each have a different `tweak` (IV).

Hex display `encr` and `C` so verify the `tweak` is there in the position you expect. In the methods debug by hex dumping all input and output: `cipher`, `tweak`,  `msg` and `self.key`.

In `decrypt` put `enc[16:]` in a temporary variable to better isolate the functions and get debug output.

As Artjom B. points out there are two separate instantiations of `AESCipher` and the init function creates the key so the keys are different so we expect the encrypted data to be different.

That the instantiations are different: `BC` and `AESCipher` makes it more difficult to see the issue.

Comment: hexdumpting you mean printing out in hex or using the library?

Comment: I think I understand why they are different, but the decryption still does not work. What do you mean by temporary variable? have a temp = encr[16:] then have tweak = temp?

Comment: Print out in hex. The problem is encryption is a binary process, the encrypted data contains non-printable characters. Base64 encodes in such a way that there is not a 1:1 correcpondence between the bytes and characters.

Comment: Instead of `unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc[16:] ))` use `encryptedMsg =  enc[16:]` `decryptedMsg = cipher.decrypt(encryptedMsg)`  `unpad(decryptedMsg)`, that way you can examine all the actual inputs to and output from `cipher.decrypt`. "If you can't see the problem, you can't fix the problem" (Credit to Willie Jack). Actually the padding is suspect.